# Android studio 1.4 grade sync fails- file lock is unsupported

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, file-locking

I've looked into other questions relating to grade issues and I cannot find anything that relates to the cause I am seeing.

I am learning to develop android applications as part of my independent study programming course. Because this is being done on a school computer, I have been dealing with some odd behavior from android studio.
Most of the issues I was able to fix, but there is one that I cannot find a solution to, and it is locking me out of any debugging tools and the Android Device Manager.

Almost immediately after loading a project, I get an error saying "grade sync failed" and am pointed towards a massive stack dump. Gradle attempts to create a file lock on some file that I cannot identify. An UnsupportedOperationException is thrown with the message "File locking is not supported".

So I came up with a possible solution. This is almost certainly being caused by the VM nature of the environment I'm using, so would moving the android SDK and gradle tools to my flash drive fix the problem? (64G, file size isn't an issue). Where are those grade files stored and how can I instruct Android studio to their new location?

Side note that I do not have any administrative permissions.